# Relative frequencies of a list of numbers

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need to find out the relative frequencies of a list of numbers. I'm almost done but I need to round the given numbers to 8 digits like this:

```
def counts2frequencies(counts):

       freq = counts2frequencies(counts)
    Input argument:
       counts: list with numbers
    Output argument:
       freq: list with frequencies
    Example: 
       counts2frequencies([8,2,3,10,5])
       =>
       [0.28571429, 0.07142857, 0.10714286, 0.35714286, 0.17857143]
```

I tried this:

```
total = float(sum(counts))
freq = []
for count in counts:
    freq.append(float(count/total))
return(freq)
```

And out comes:

```
counts2frequencies([8,2,3,10,5])

Out[51]: 
[0.2857142857142857,
0.07142857142857142,
0.10714285714285714,
0.35714285714285715,
0.17857142857142858]
```

How do I round the numbers in the list? The function `round()` doesn't work somehow.

Comment: What do you mean by *doesn't work somehow*? Your numbers look correct, why are the extra digits a problem exactly?

Comment: Take into account that floating point numbers are an **approximation**. You cannot express every possible real number with a float, as they approximate numbers using binary fractions (0 or 1 times 1/2 + 0 or 1 times 1/4 + 0 or 1 times 1/8, etc.)

Comment: That is true but the task is, that we have to get the answer as shown in the example. This is why I wanted to round the numbers to 8 digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Round to 8 decimal places:

```
>>> l
[0.2857142857142857, 0.07142857142857142, 0.10714285714285714,
 0.35714285714285715, 0.17857142857142858]
>>> lrounded = [ round(i, 8) for i in l ]
[0.28571429, 0.07142857, 0.10714286, 0.35714286, 0.17857143]
```

Though, the **right** way is to round them when printing, with `'{:.08f}'.format(i)`:

```
>>> print('{:.08f}'.format(0.07142857142857142))
0.07142857
>>> print('{:.08f}'.format(0.07))
0.07000000
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I tried it with your solutions but it doesn't work: The function should also work directly for other lists, so if i give the command counts2frequencies([8,2,3,10,5]) with other numbers, there should come out a list with already rounded numbers. So I tried it like this: freqrounded = [ round(i, 8) for i in freq ] but the numbers I get are the same ad before. So is there another way or am I doing it wrong? Or should I change my whole function, so it works properly?